# I am using ViewModel Live data for UI update. I want to use Retrofit for network calls. Can I use retrofit calls in Service(intent Service)?

Tags: android

I have an activity (MainActivity) and I am using ViewModel Live data for UI update. I want to use Retrofit for network calls.

If I use service how can i use LiveData in service ,is there a way for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a Retrofit in a Service, as it (Service) is not intended for this purpose (in most situations).
If you have a small application, you can, bypassing the clean architecture, make calls directly to the ViewModel and use the LiveData there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That make sense but If want have some kind service which part architecture it comes usually ?  Do we need have Retrofit calls in any async task kind of stuff? help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ofc we should call Retrofit in another thread. U can use for this AcyncTasks (very bad option), RxJava, Coroutines or enqueue() method of Retrofit API Interface.

Comment: We shouldn't call long-running methods (request method can be time-consuming due to a bad connection or many other things) on the Service, since the Service can killed by system along with our request. 
If you want to postpone work or want it to run even when the application is killed - use WorkManager.